# Optimizing MySQL query with SUM, date range and Group By

Tags: mysql

I have following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stats (
    date date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
    cid int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    v bigint(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    c bigint(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    a bigint(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (date,cid),
KEY date (date),
KEY cid (cid),
KEY date_cid_vca (date,cid,v,c,a)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

this table has **30,842,712** rows

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS camp (
id int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (id,name)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

this table has **1985** rows

**I have the following query:**

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    SUM(s.v) AS sumv,
    SUM(s.c) AS sumc,
    GREATEST(((SUM(s.c)/SUM(s.v))*100.00), 0.00) AS cratio,
    SUM(s.a) AS suma,
    GREATEST(((SUM(s.a)/SUM(s.c))*100.00), 0.00) AS aratio
FROM
    stats s, camp c
WHERE
    s.date >= '2012-02-01' AND
    s.date <= '2012-02-29' AND
    c.id=s.cid
GROUP BY s.cid;
```

**EXPLAIN shows:**

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                 | key          | key_len | ref                 | rows    | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | range | PRIMARY,date,cid,date_cid_vca | date_cid_vca | 3       | NULL                | 1010265 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref   | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY      | 4       | db.s.cid            |       1 | Using index                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Problem is that the query takes around 50 seconds to complete even though it uses indexes. Is there any other way to optimize the query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've done well in optimizing this query with your indexes. I suppose you really do have over 1 million rows in `stats` in that date range. Unfortunately, joining (and then grouping) 1 million rows, even with a covering index, is a lot to ask from a database. For better performance, you will need to beef up the hardware, start denormalizing (put `camp` inside of `stats` to avoid the join), or keep running totals for each camp instead of calculating it on the fly.

**Edit**

Since removing the 1 million+ joins seemed to have made a large impact, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT c.*, a.* FROM
(SELECT
    SUM(s.v) AS sumv,
    SUM(s.c) AS sumc,
    GREATEST(((SUM(s.c)/SUM(s.v))*100.00), 0.00) AS cratio,
    SUM(s.a) AS suma,
    GREATEST(((SUM(s.a)/SUM(s.c))*100.00), 0.00) AS aratio,
    s.cid
FROM
    stats s
WHERE
    s.date >= '2012-02-01'
   AND s.date <= '2012-02-29'
GROUP BY s.cid) a
JOIN
  camp c
  ON c.id = a.cid
```

This query does the join on the smaller result set.

Comment: I think hardware is not the issue. Server has 4 CPUs with 8 cores (32 cores, 64 threads) and 64GB RAM. It has 6x SSD disks in RAID 10. my.cnf is maximum optimized (based on tuning-primer.sh). Can you please give more info on denormalizing. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried removing join and then pulling data from camp with separate query within data loop from main query. I guess it is the way to go because now total execution time reduced enormously. It takes around 10 seconds to complete.

Comment: Sounds like nice, beefy, hardware. :)

Comment: this query is superb. You only forgot to add GROUP BY in the subquery. It takes the same time as my query without JOIN. Thanks!

Comment: @Paxxil, I added the missing `GROUP BY`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following query should allow it to use indexes more efficiently

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    SUM(s.v) AS sumv,
    SUM(s.c) AS sumc,
    GREATEST(((SUM(s.c)/SUM(s.v))*100.00), 0.00) AS cratio,
    SUM(s.a) AS suma,
    GREATEST(((SUM(s.a)/SUM(s.c))*100.00), 0.00) AS aratio
FROM
    camp c
INNER JOIN
    stats s
ON
    s.cid = c.id
    AND s.date BETWEEN '2012-02-01' AND '2012-02-29'

GROUP BY c.id;
```

Also I would consider deleting the date_cid_vca key as it is just containing the entire table and so not particularly useful.  The above query should use the PK to match rows from stats to camp based on date and cid and so while it'shard to be 100% certain without access to your database, I'm fairly confident that the above will improve your response times

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but unfortunately it takes around 5 seconds longer to execute your version of the query. Without index date_cid_vca it takes twice as much time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Inner join with your C table, and in the join use the dates conditions, it should reduce the time of your query.

You could probably do more optimizations but thats the first 1 i could see.