# Optimizing SQL query with multiple joins. Need advice on techniques to retrieve data fast and efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, subquery

I have a query that gets the product description from `product` table (1st select) then subtracts it to the following subquery statements to get the no. of stocks remaining:

-sum of each product **stocks** in the `inventory` table (2nd)

-sum of each product **sold** in the `sales_detail` table (3rd)

-sum of each product **transferred to another branch** in the `stock_transfer` table (4th)

-sum of each product that **got damaged** in the `damaged_product` table (5th)

The problem is every time this query loads, it goes full search of all 4 tables to get the sum of the `quantity` columns. And as time goes by, more records are stored and the query will become slower. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT p.Id,p.Product_Name Product,p.Description, c.Category_Name Category,sc.Subcategory_Name Subcategory,s.Supplier_Name Supplier, p.Selling_Price `Unit Price`,i.Stocks,s.Sales, i.Stocks - IFNULL(s.Sales, 0) - IFNULL(t.Transfer, 0) - IFNULL(d.Damage, 0) AS Remaining

FROM (SELECT Id, Product_Name, Description, Selling_Price, Category_Id, Subcategory_Id, Supplier_Id       FROM product WHERE enable_flag = 1) p

LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT product_id, COALESCE(SUM(quantity), 0) AS Stocks
                FROM inventory
                WHERE enable_flag = 1 GROUP BY product_id) i ON p.Id = i.product_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT product_id, COALESCE(SUM(quantity), 0) AS Sales
                FROM sales_detail
                WHERE enable_flag = 1 GROUP BY product_id) s USING(product_id)

LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT product_id, COALESCE(SUM(transfer_quantity), 0) AS Transfer
                FROM stock_transfer
                WHERE enable_flag = 1 GROUP BY product_id) t USING(product_id)

LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT product_id, COALESCE(SUM(damaged_quantity), 0) AS Damage
                FROM damaged_product
                WHERE enable_flag = 1 GROUP BY product_id) d USING(product_id)

JOIN Category c ON p.Category_Id=c.Id

JOIN Subcategory sc ON p.Subcategory_Id=sc.Id

JOIN Supplier s ON p.Supplier_Id=s.Id;
```

Comment: Indexing columns has a great impact on query performance.

Are the internal and external keys indexed in all the tables involved query?

Comment: I believe that primary keys in MySql are automatically indexed when created, same goes for foreign keys. I need to check if all my `WHERE` statements in the `JOIN` clause were all indexed. Thanks

Comment: I'm referring to columns similar to a user_id in this example, unindexed foreign keys:

CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
 id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 user_id INT NOT NULL,
 firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 email VARCHAR(50),
 reg_date TIMESTAMP
)


Also, here is a similar post that may give you a hint.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330204/optimizing-mysql-query-with-sum-date-range-and-group-by

Comment: I just generated the sql file of my database by exporting it and found out that there's no `INDEX` statement anywhere. But in my diagram, there's a INDEX defined. Please see screenshot: https://postimg.org/image/mmi2so9s3/ Can you please check if this is the automatic index generated? And do you know why it isn't defined when creating the sql statement?

Comment: No date range limiting the query?

Comment: @Rick James I'm afraid there's none. I need to get the sum of a specific item bought by the store(since the beginning) and subtract it to the same item bought by the customers(since the beginning). So I'm always checking the whole table for all items. Any better suggestions?

Comment: Summary tables would make it much more efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure how to read the image you linked to but please do make sure  Category_Id, Subcategory_Id and Supplier_Id are indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forcing a full groupby on the subtables, which is unnecessary.

```
SELECT Id, Product_Name Product, Description, Category_Name Category, Subcategory_Name Subcategory,
Supplier_Name Supplier, Selling_Price 'Unit Price', 
Stocks, Sales, Stocks - Sales - Transfer - Damage AS Remaining
FROM    
(select p.*, sc.Subcategory_Name, s.Supplier_Name, 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM inventory WHERE enable_flag = 1 and product_id = p.Id),0) as Stocks,
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM sales_detail WHERE enable_flag = 1 and product_id = p.Id),0) as Sales,
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(transfer_quantity) FROM stock_transfer WHERE enable_flag = 1 and product_id = p.Id),0) as Transfer,
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(damaged_quantity) FROM damaged_product WHERE enable_flag = 1 and product_id = p.Id),0) as Damage
FROM product p
JOIN Category c ON p.Category_Id=c.Id
JOIN Subcategory sc ON p.Subcategory_Id=sc.Id
JOIN Supplier s ON p.Supplier_Id=s.Id
WHERE enable_flag = 1
) p
```

And ofcourse, you should ensure you have indexes on `product_id` on `inventory`, `sales_detail`, `stock_transfer`, `damaged_product`, plus `Category_Id` on `Category`, `Subcategory_Id` on `Subcategory`, and finally `Supplier_Id` on `Supplier`

Comment: I thought I still need `GROUP BY` to sum each product id. Just to clarify, the job of grouping the sum of each product is being done by the `and product_id = p.Id` alone?

Comment: You only need a group by if you care about ALL the values for every single product. e.g. if you wanted to compare the current products damaged goods to the average number of damaged goods. But here you care only about each individual product, and thus a plain normal select sub query is fine. (Notice, select subqueries are always outer joins)

Comment: By the way, your first `IFNULL` lacks an open parenthesis and you have semi-colon before the last `WHERE` clause. Thanks so much for your help, I'll get back to you after I tested the query :)

Comment: Upon testing in MySql Workbench, my posted query has a duration time of 0.874 sec and fetch time of 0.016 sec. Yours only has a duration of 0.375 sec but a fetch time of 0.436 sec. I noticed that it greatly improved in the duration time, thanks @Cine!. I'm just a little bothered with the fetch time, because I have no idea what it is haha/ When I have time I'll try to implement it in my program so I can check the improvements in real world. Thanks again!

Comment: don't worry I'll mark it once I've implemented it in my program this day